# Stability and perturbed form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

If we want to show stability for a scheme like this:
\begin{align*}
p_{n+1}&=y_n+\frac{1}{2}h[3f(t_n,y_n)-f(t_{n},y_{n})]\\
y_{n+1}&=y_{n-1}+\frac{h}{3}[f(t_{n+1},p_{n+1})+4f(t_{n},y_{n})+f(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})]\\
\end{align*}
Do we then have two errors $\varepsilon_n$ in the perturbed form

> \begin{align*}
> p_{n+1}&=y_n+\frac{1}{2}h[3f(t_n,y_n)-f(t_{n},y_{n})]+ \varepsilon_{n,1}\\
> y_{n+1}&=y_{n-1}+\frac{h}{3}[f(t_{n+1},p_{n+1})+4f(t_{n},y_{n})+f(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})]+ \varepsilon_{n,2}\\
> \end{align*}

Or only one in the second one:

> \begin{align*}
> p_{n+1}&=y_n+\frac{1}{2}h[3f(t_n,y_n)-f(t_{n},y_{n})]\\
> y_{n+1}&=y_{n-1}+\frac{h}{3}[f(t_{n+1},p_{n+1})+4f(t_{n},y_{n})+f(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})]+ \varepsilon_{n}\\
> \end{align*}

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I think if $f$ is at least Lipshitz-continuous which is probably the case, then $\varepsilon_{n,1}$ can be considered as a part of $\varepsilon_n$ (just by replacing perturbed $p_{n+1}$ by unperturbed $p_{n+1}$) so you need to consider only one perturbation.

Comment: @VorKir Thank you for the answer. What is the argument that Lipschitz is enough for the unperturbed $p_{n+1}$?

Comment: I thought about representing $f(t_{n+1},p_{n+1}^{perturbed})$ as the sum $f(t_{n+1},p_{n+1}^{unperturbed}) + (f(t_{n+1},p_{n+1}^{perturbed}) - f(t_{n+1},p_{n+1}^{unperturbed}))$ and considering the second term as an additive for the $\varepsilon_n$. The question is then whether you can loose stability in the sense that small perturbation for $p_{n+1}$ will lead to a non-small (small means infinitesimal) additive for $\varepsilon_n$. But if $f$ is Lipshitz, then this term can be estimated as $(f(t_{n+1},p_{n+1}^{perturbed}) - f(t_{n+1},p_{n+1}^{unperturbed})) \leq C_f \varepsilon_{n,1}$

Comment: @VorKir Hm yes but unfortuantely that would mean that we have a $hC_f\epsilon_{n,1}$ meaning it is not stable?

Comment: You're right about presence of $h$ factor. But doesn't it say then that  $\varepsilon_{n,1}$ perturbation for $p_{n+1}$ is leading to not more than $h C_f \varepsilon_{n,1}$ additional perturbation for $y_{n+1}$? So it is ok, no? I might be misreading or misunderstanding something.